# Qual o uso prático de operadores bitwise em PHP?

Tags: php, bitwise

Os operadores [bit a bit](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.bitwise.php), utilizados para manipulação de bits específicos, são um tanto quanto incomuns (para não dizer raros) o seu uso em uma aplicação `PHP`. Se falarmos sobre `escovação de bits` em linguagens compiladas, como `C/C++`, é mais fácil entender devido ao nível de contato maior com o hardware (Microcontrolador, Arduíno, Raspberry).

Em PHP, qual o uso prático de utilizá-los?

Comment: O mesmo que em qq outra linguagem. Saber se um número é par, multiplicar/dividir por potencias de 2 mais rapidamente, juntar flags, fazer mapas de bit para filtrar resultados de DB, etc. Sabendo usar, tem muita coisa que fica mais prática e rápida bit a bit. É que geralmente quem aprende só PHP fica muito no superficial, já que a linguagem é basicamente usada pra scripts simples (que são artificialmente complicados com academicismo de outras linguagens, em muitos casos).

Comment: @Bacco responde ai com alguns exemplos :D

Comment: @rray espero que alguém o faça, só pus um comment pra adiantar o assunto. Seria bem legal uma reposta com pequenos algoritmos exemplo. Se sobrar um tempo mais tarde, posso tentar fazer algo. Mas eu prefiro que a comunidade vá postando exemplos, fica mais legal com várias respostas. Se você (ou alguém) quiser pegar alguns dos exemplos que eu disse e usar em resposta própria, fique à vontade.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para quem ficou boiando, vamos a um exemplo prático no mundo real

Imagine que você construiu um sistema onde precise implementar diversos níveis de acesso.

Exemplo, permitir ou negar uma área do sistema, permitir ou negar a edição de um grupo de texto, etc.

Normalmente faríamos algo exaustivo e difícil de gerenciar assim

```
tabela permissões:
     usuario_id
     editar
     adicionar
     deletar
     desativar
     ver
```

Numa consulta SQL ficaria algo como `SELECT editar, adicionar, deletar FROM ...`

Parece simples, porém, imagine quando precisar adicionar mais permissões.

Terá que criar novas colunas e adicionar implementações nos scripts do sistema.

Usando operadores bitwise, poderia simplificar assim

```
tabela permissões:
     usuario_id
     bit_flag
```

Então você pergunta, como vou saber se esse usuário pode editar, adicionar, etc?

Com apenas 1 coluna numérica, poderá identificar diversas permissões.

Exemplo, suponha que a consulta `SELECT bit_flag FROM  ...` retorne o número 79.

Com isso, temos a seguinte rotina:

```
$rs = 79; // o que retornou do banco

function showPermission($rs, $b)
{
    return 'Acesso '.$b.' '.(($rs & $b)? 'permitido' : 'negado');
}

echo showPermission($rs, 1).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 2).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 4).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 8).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 16).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 32).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 64).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
echo showPermission($rs, 128).PHP_EOL.'<br />';
```

Retornará:

```
Acesso 1 permitido
Acesso 2 permitido
Acesso 4 permitido
Acesso 8 permitido
Acesso 16 negado
Acesso 32 negado
Acesso 64 permitido
Acesso 128 negado
```

Note que 79 é justamente a soma de 1, 2, 4, 8 e 64.

Modifique o número para 78 e verá que a permissão 1 mudará para "negado".

No sistema você define como quiser o que cada operando representa.

Exemplo,

```
1 -> representa adicionar
2 -> representa editar
4 -> representa deletar
```

Esse é apenas um simplório exemplo do que pode fazer com operadores bitwise. Não somente no PHP mas em outras linguagens também.

Comment: Ótimo! Pode ser simplório mas começou a clarear as ideias.

Comment: Só não entendi porque isso daqui: $rs & $b daria true ou false, poderia explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está uma pergunta interessante, mas discordo totalmente da afirmação da sua pergunta onde menciona:

> ... em linguagens compiladas, como C/C++,é mais fácil entender devido ao nível de contato maior com o hardware ...

É certo que essa é apenas uma das várias aplicações do `bit a bit`, no entanto, no `PHP` e apesar do ser uma linguagem de `script` desenvolvida em C, não deixa e dependendo da necessidade de cada implementação de ser necessário toda a operacionalidade `bitwise`.

A melhor resposta que posso entregar além de evocar situações académicas é indicar alguma prática, isto para fugir um pouco à resposta básica de permissões de administração que são erradas em muitos níveis e nada tem a ver com o mundo real de um programador.

Assim aqui vai um caso de aplicabilidade:

Imagine um identificador único para um serviço online onde qualquer utilizador terá de ter um número único no serviço. Este irá ter o seu registo em um dos servidores de dados que serão vários de suporte ao serviço. Para baralhar mais, o identificador deve ainda de conter um estilo de *check digit* para validação instantânea.

*Uma forma de atingir isto é com o bit a bit.*

Ao invés de ter três campos, podemos ter um campo único que agregue todos. Mesmo os três campos não responderiam ao requisito de ter um identificador único.

Imagine um inteiro de 32 bits, mas o mesmo é válido para 64 bits.

Assim e tendo em conta o limite de 32 bits (esquema fictício apenas para retratar o que exponho) podemos agrupar os bits da seguinte forma:

```
00000000 - 0000000000000000000 - 0000 = valor único num inteiro de 32 bits
    |               |              |
    |               |              |-- 4 bits - até 15 valor do check-digit
    |               |
    |               |-- 20 bits - até 1.048.575 valor único na tabela do srv
    |              
    |--- 8 bits - índice do servidor até 255 servidores
```

Assim conseguimos juntar estes três campos distintos num inteiro apenas, obtendo em consequência um número sempre único e de funcionalidade extra. Penso expor bem, que também em `PHP` este tipo de operações são muito necessárias.

Neste caso que coloco e a titulo de exemplo imagine que o utilizador entrega o seu código único, junto do serviço. De imediato é possível validar a integridade do identificador entregue, depois, apontar de imediato para o servidor onde se encontra o seu registo e obter os seus dados. Esta é de certa forma, como alguns sistemas funcionam.

Este tipo de campo/estrutura tem o nome de `bit field`. Do wiki obtem:

> A bit field is a term used in computer programming to store multiple,
>   logical, neighboring bits, where each of the sets of bits, and single
>   bits can be addressed. A bit field is most commonly used to represent
>   integral types of known, fixed bit-width.

Muitas são as vantagens na utilização de **Bit fields** e em casos reais são muito utilizados.

Comment: Sim sim, o comentário foi apenas uma generalização e um pequeno exemplo do uso do bit a bit.

Answer (score 1):

PHP é uma linguagem de uso geral, pode ser usada para potencialmente qualquer coisa. Aparecem situações em que mesmo uma linguagem de alto nível precisa interagir com números binários e operações bitwise. Por exemplo:

- interpretar um arquivo com formato binário
- fazer comunicação de rede, e o protocolo é binário
- representação compacta de diversos estados, "flags" ou opções Sim/Não. Um número de 0 a 255 pode representar 8 estados independentes, e "ler" cada bit é mais rápido usando operadores bitwise
- criptografia, cálculo de hashes ou dígitos verificadores. Com os operadores bitwise, pode-se implementar essas coisas em PHP puro, do contrário seria necessário escrever em C.

Answer (score 0):

Achei indispensavel usar bitwise nesse algoritimo. Ele é bem rápido pra encontrar combinações de valores sobre um valor. No caso estou pesquisando 17.2 O Algoritimo vai me retornar a chave b e c+d...

```
        $values     = array('a' => '12.8', 'b' => '17.2', 'c' => '10.2', 'd' => '5');
        $target     = explode('.', number_format(17.2, 2)); // VALOR ESPERADO
        $len        = count($values);


        for($i = 1; $i < pow(2, $len); $i++){
            $soma   = 0;
            $set    = array();
            for($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++){
                if(1 << $j & $i){ // MAGICA
                    $set[] = $j;
                    $soma += $values[$j];
                }
            }

            $soma   = explode('.', number_format($soma, 2));
            if($soma[0] == $target[0] && $soma[1] == $target[1]){
                foreach($set as $pos){
                    $ids[] = $values[$pos];
                }
                return $ids;
            }
        }
```