# Como verificar se um número é par ou ímpar?

Tags: php

Como faço para descobrir se um determinado número que está armazenado numa variável é par ou ímpar com PHP?

Comment: Gonçalo, conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 11):

No PHP, como pode haver em várias outras linguagens, uma forma de saber se um número é par ou ímpar, pode se usar o operador `%`, que significar [MOD](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/internals2.opcodes.mod.php), para calcular o "resto" da divisão do valor. Se o resto do número tem valor zero, então sabemos que o resultado é par. Segue abaixo:

```
if($valor % 2 == 0){
     echo "par";
} else {
     echo "impar";
}
```

Código simplificado usando [operador ternário](http://blog.alura.com.br/o-que-e-o-operador-ternario/):

```
echo !($valor % 2) ? "par" : "impar";
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra alternativa com o [operador *bitwise*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.bitwise.php) `&`:

```
$numero = 3;

if ( $numero & 1 ) {
  echo "$numero é impar!";
} else {
  echo "$numero é par!";
}
```

O operador `&` faz a comparação dos valores usando sua forma binária, cada *bit* é comparado, retornando *1* quando ambos os *bits* forem iguais a *1*, caso contrário retorna *0*.

No exemplo acima o número *3* em binário é *00000011* e *1* é *00000001*, o resultado dessa operação é *00000001*, o número mais a direita é *1* (e nesse caso indica que é um número ímpar) ou é *0*, que indica que é um número par.

Veja um exemplo:

```
  00000011 // 3
& 00000001 // 1
= 00000001 (ímpar)

  00000110 // 6
& 00000001 // 1
= 00000000 (par)
```

Veja também: [**Qual o uso prático de operadores bitwise em PHP?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116051/6454)

Comment: Muito bom Stderr! Mas tem um pequeno detalhe. Faça um caso de teste sendo `$numero = 9209458740945999;` , e veja o resultado.

Comment: Acontece nos dois casos, usando `mod` e usando `bitwise`.

Comment: @CleidimarViana Valeu. :) Para corrigir isso, você teria que usar o [`BC Math`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) ou [`GMP`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) ou outra alternativa. Por exemplo, com o BC Math da para usar a função [`bcmod`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bcmod.php) veja um [**exemplo**](http://ideone.com/dPzpUi).