# Por que 1^2 é 3 e por que quando exibo 0x33 aparece 51 e 022 aparece 18?

Tags: php

Porque isso:

```
echo 1 ^ 2;
```

é igual a 3?

E porque isso:

```
echo 0x33, ' birds sit on ', 022, ' trees.';
```

é igual a isso: “51 birds sit on 18 trees” ?

Comment: Sobre o segundo código, `0x33` é o hexadecimal para 51 e `022` é o octal para 18. Relacioanda: [O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/91)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual o uso prático de operadores bitwise em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116051/qual-o-uso-pr%C3%A1tico-de-operadores-bitwise-em-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Por que `1^2 = 3`?

Porque o operador `^` é um operador bit a bit que executa a operação XOR entre os operandos. Se imaginarmos as representações binárias dos números (considerando apenas 2 bits - quantidade mínima para representar os dois valores):

```
1 = 01
2 = 10
```

Fazendo o XOR bit a bit temos:

```
1 ^ 2 = 0 1 ^ 1 0 = (0 xor 1) (1 xor 0) = 11
        ⌊_|___⌋─|───────┘         |
          ⌊_____⌋─────────────────┘
```

Ou seja, `1^2` resulta o número binário 11, que é o número 3 em decimal.

> Por qua a mensagem “51 birds sit on 18 trees”?

Porque o valor `0x33` é uma representação hexadecimal do número 51 em decimal, assim como o valor `022` é a representação octal do número 18 decimal.

**Relacionadas**

[O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/91)

[Qual o uso prático de operadores bitwise em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116051/qual-o-uso-pr%C3%A1tico-de-operadores-bitwise-em-php)

[Documentação oficial: Operadores bit a bit (bitwise)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro caso, o sinal de `^` em php faz parte dos operadores bit a bit. No caso o 
`^` é `XOR` (OR exclusivo), Os bits que estão ativos em `$a` ou em `$b`, mas não em ambos, são ativado.

Então

```
1 ^ 2 = 0001 ^ 0010 = 0011 = 3
```

`0x33` é a representação em hexa de 51.

E

`022` é o octal para 18.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo:

```
<?php
// 00001010
$a = 10;
// 01101001
$b = 105;

$c = $a ^ $b;
#   01101001
# & 00001010
# = 01100011

// Exibe 99 Na tela
// 01100011
echo $c;
?>
```

Então echo 1 ^ 2 é:

```
1 = 01
2 = 10
    11 = 3
```

Como o rray falou:

> Sobre o segundo código, 0x33 é o hexadecimal para 51 e 022 é o octal
>   para 18.

Fonte: https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/06/operadores-bit-bit-em-php/